# custom JSON sort_keys order in Python

Tags: python, json, sorting

Is there any way in Python 2.6 to supply a custom key or cmp function to JSON's sort_keys?

I've got a list of dicts coming from JSON like so:

```
[
  {
    "key": "numberpuzzles1",
    "url": "number-puzzle-i.html",
    "title": "Number Puzzle I",
    "category": "nestedloops",
    "points": "60",
    "n": "087"
  },
  {
     "key": "gettingindividualdigits",
     "url": "getting-individual-digits.html",
     "title": "Getting Individual Digits",
     "category": "nestedloops",
     "points": "80",
     "n": "088"
  }
]
```

...which I've stored into the list variable `assigndb`.  I'd like to be able to load in the JSON, modify it, and serialized it back out with `dumps` (or whatever), keeping the *orders of the keys intact*.

So far, I've tried something like this:

```
ordering = {'key': 0, 'url': 1, 'title': 2, 'category': 3,
             'flags': 4, 'points': 5, 'n': 6}

def key_func(k):
    return ordering[k]

# renumber assignments sequentially
for (i, a) in enumerate(assigndb):
    a["n"] = "%03d" % (i+1)

s = json.dumps(assigndb, indent=2, sort_keys=True, key=key_func)
```

...but of course `dumps` doesn't support a custom key like `list.sort()` does.  Something with a custom `JSONEncoder` maybe?  I can't seem to get it going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of ugly, but in case tokland's solution does not work for you:

```
data = [{'category': 'nestedloops', 'title': 'Number Puzzle I', 'url': 'number-puzzle-i.html', 'n': '087', 'points': '60', 'key': 'numberpuzzles1'}, {'category': 'nestedloops', 'title': 'Getting Individual Digits', 'url': 'getting-individual-digits.html', 'n': '088', 'points': '80', 'key': 'gettingindividualdigits'}]
ordering = {'key': 0, 'url': 1, 'title': 2, 'category': 3,
            'flags': 4, 'points': 5, 'n': 6}
outlist = []
for d in data:
    outlist.append([])
    for k in sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: ordering[k]):
        outlist[-1].append(json.dumps({k: d[k]}))

for i, l in enumerate(outlist):
    outlist[i] = "{" + ",".join((s[1:-1] for s in outlist[i])) + "}"

s = "[" + ",".join(outlist) + "]"
```

Answer (score 11):

An idea (tested with 2.7):

```
import json
import collections
json.encoder.c_make_encoder = None
d = collections.OrderedDict([("b", 2), ("a", 1)])
json.dumps(d)
# '{"b": 2, "a": 1}'
```

See: [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) + [issue6105](http://bugs.python.org/issue6105). The `c_make_encoder` hack seems only to be needed  for Python 2.x. Not a direct solution because you have to change `dict`s for `OrderedDict`s, but it may be still usable. I checked the json library ([encode.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e1e5423815a4/Lib/json/encoder.py#l338)) and the ordered is hardcoded:

```
if _sort_keys:
    items = sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])
```

Comment: This _might_ work, but the dicts are coming from JSON initially, and so the keys are already unordered.

Comment: Meh.  OrderedDict is 2.7 only.

Comment: @Graham: regardless the python version there are several modules that implement ordered dicts, pick any of them.

Comment: The `c_make_encoder = None` part doesn't seem to be needed on 2.7.3.

Comment: Works great on 2.7.8. Don't forget to remove the `sort_keys = True` in `json.dumps` (It doesn't work if you leave it!)

Answer (score 2):

Compact yet powerful recursive implementation with "prepended" and "appended" keys: https://gist.github.com/jeromerg/91f73d5867c5fa04ee7dbc0c5a03d611

```py
def sort_recursive(node, first_keys, last_keys):
    """ Sort the dictionary entries in a whole JSON object tree"""
    fixed_placements = {
        **{key: (0, idx) for idx, key in enumerate(first_keys)},
        **{key: (2, idx) for idx, key in enumerate(last_keys)},
    }
    return _sort_recursive(node, lambda key: fixed_placements.get(key, (1, key)))


def _sort_recursive(node, key_fn):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        return [_sort_recursive(val, key_fn) for val in node]
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        sorted_keys = sorted(node.keys(), key=key_fn)
        return {k:_sort_recursive(node[k], key_fn) for k in sorted_keys}
    else:
        return node
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and `collections.OrderedDict` was just not fit for the task because it ordered everything alphabetically. So I wrote something similar to Andrew Clark's solution:

```
def json_dumps_sorted(data, **kwargs):
    sorted_keys = kwargs.get('sorted_keys', tuple())
    if not sorted_keys:
        return json.dumps(data)
    else:
        out_list = []
        for element in data:
            element_list = []
            for key in sorted_keys:
                if key in element:
                    element_list.append(json.dumps({key: element[key]}))
            out_list.append('{{{}}}'.format(','.join((s[1:-1] for s in element_list))))
        return '[{}]'.format(','.join(out_list))
```

You use it like this:

```
json_string = json_dumps_sorted([
    {
        "key": "numberpuzzles1",
        "url": "number-puzzle-i.html",
        "title": "Number Puzzle I",
        "category": "nestedloops",
        "points": "60",
        "n": "087"
    }, {
        "key": "gettingindividualdigits",
        "url": "getting-individual-digits.html",
        "title": "Getting Individual Digits",
        "category": "nestedloops",
        "points": "80",
        "n": "088"
    }
], sorted_keys=(
    'key', 
    'url', 
    'title', 
    'category',
    'flags', 
    'points', 
    'n'
))
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. I needed to put a timestamp key:value at the top of my JSON object no matter what. Obviously sorting the keys screwed this up as it starts with "t".

Using something like this, while putting the timestamp key in the dict_data right away worked:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict(dict_data)
```